# How to change bar fillColor in chart.js bar char

Tags: chart.js

I use chart.js to draw a bar chart. How to change the bar fill color in chart.js.(I use the 'Bar chart' )

```js
    var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the `fillColor : "rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)` mean? How can I change this color?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the css rgba color style. I think I've known how to change this~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rgba stands for red green blue alpha. The parameters are as follows:

```
rgba(x, y, z, w)
```

- x: amount of red (0-255)
- y: amount of green (0-255)
- z: amount of blue (0-255)
- w: alpha value (opacity). 1 is fully opaque, 0 is fully transparent

You can also specify [Hex values](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colorsfull.asp) as colours:

```
{
    fillColor : "#ffff00",
    strokeColor : "#000000",
    data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
}
```

or predefined [colour names](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp) instead if you don't want to use rgba values:

```
{
    fillColor : "yellow",
    strokeColor : "black",
    data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
}
```